# For sampling to be independent(2 random samples), do the two populations have to be independent as well?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

I was trying to think of a scenario where we draw two random samples from two different populations. Can it be a case that the samples are independent but the populations are not?

**EDIT**: By independent sampling, I mean that if I draw 1st sample with some observations, and then I draw a 2nd sample such that the probability of occurrences of observations in this sample is *independent* of the observations I got in the 1st sample. My question is, can this happen even if the populations of the two samples are dependent (let's say as an extreme case, if the populations are same)?

Comment: What does it mean for two samples to be independent?  What you've written is quite vague...can you try to sharpen your question?

Comment: You might be confusing the linguistic or colloquial meaning of the word "independent" with the *mathematical* meaning of the word "independent."  You might also be confusing the word "*disjoint*" or "*exclusive*" here as well.

Comment: Now... when we talk about independence in probability, we are referring specifically to *events* being independent or not... not outcomes.  We can indeed draw multiple times without replacement and have the *events* described be independent.  For instance, if you draw two cards from a standard deck of cards without replacement, the *event* that the first card is a king is independent of the *event* that the second card is a heart.  This, even despite it being the same deck that both cards were drawn from.  It didn't need to be two different distinct decks for it to be independent.

Comment: @JMoravitz I have edited my question. Maybe have a look at it now?

Comment: What do you mean with a population?